# What is in a blank string in Parse.com

Tags: xcode, nsstring, parse-platform

I have a custom column in my user class called school and I want to check if is blank or not. Here is the code I am trying:

```
[super viewDidLoad]{
if ([currentUser[@"school"] isEqualToString:@"undefined"] || [currentUser[@"school"] isEqualToString:@"(undefined)"] || [currentUser[@"school"] isEqualToString:@""] || [currentUser[@"school"] isEqualToString:@" "]){
        NSLog(@"the column is blank");
   }
}
```

but the NSLog seems to not be true, not sure why?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: blank and " " are different things... "" would be an empty string, the first one has a space in it.

Comment: @Fosco Yes I have set one of the isEqualToString@"" (there is nothing in between, no space no nothing) one has a space because I was checking if there was a space but it still doesn't work

Comment: you should NSLog the value of the field then and see what's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check a blank string in parse. Is to check the length of the string.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
if([user[@"school"] length] > 0) {
//do something
}
```